# How to keep npm dependency in non minified form

Tags: javascript, npm

I am trying to debug an issue in my repository which uses an npm package as a dependency (let's call it 'somedep'). Now somedep is owned by another team in my organization which uses rollup to minify and publish the package which we then consume for our repository. Now there's a bug which I'm trying to debug. I can't seem to debug it efficiently because the code from somedep is minified. I have access to the source code (the git repo) of somedep. Is there any way for me to connect my local copy of somedep to my package?

I want it connected in a non minified form.

Comment: Could you suggest to the other team that they include sourcemaps?

Comment: Install the dependency from your local checkout instead of the repository as per the duplicate

Comment: Not sure you know this,  with Chrome there is the pretty print option that will un-minify the code..  And can often make the code look nicer than some peoples source.. :)